# Print `one_long_page` pdf using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to print [this resume site](https://nearhuscarl.github.io/portfolio/resume-full) to **within 1 page** of pdf **using puppeteer**, with the desired result is something like [this](https://nearhuscarl.github.io/portfolio/documents/resume.pdf), that desired result had used [Seija](https://www.sejda.com/developers#html-pdf-api-options), with the option of `pageSize` set to `one_long_page` (by default). pageSize of one_long_page is really what I want but I can't figure out how to achieve in puppeteer. See [Seija documentation](https://www.sejda.com/developers#html-pdf-api-options) to see that option.

[Here](https://github.com/NearHuscarl/portfolio/blob/master/scripts/htmlToPdf.js) is the script used Seija to convert html to pdf (which worked).

And here is my current puppeteer attempt: *(You can try online without installing puppeteer here: https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/)*

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('https://nearhuscarl.github.io/portfolio/resume-full', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  })

  const [width, height] = await page.evaluate(
    () => [
      document.documentElement.offsetWidth, 
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    ]
  )

  console.log(width, height)

  // await page.addStyleTag({
  //   content: `@page { size: auto; }`
  // })

  await page.pdf({
    path: 'near_resume.pdf',
    printBackground: true,
    // scale: 0.98,
    // pageRanges: '1',
    // height: pageHeight,
    // preferCSSPageSize: true,
    width,
    height,
    // margin: { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
  })

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Current result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I've come up with to make it *nearly work*, with a lot of hacks. Can't find a simple solution like `pageSize: one_long_page` even when it looks so trivial.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const url = 'https://nearhuscarl.github.io/portfolio/resume-full'
const viewportWidth = 1000
const output = 'near_resume.pdf'

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    defaultViewport: { 
      width: +viewportWidth + 1, // THE HACK to make it work
      height: 0 
    }
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
  })

  const [width, height] = await page.evaluate(() => [
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth, 
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight
  ])

  console.log(width, height)

  await page.pdf({
    path: output,
    printBackground: true,
    pageRanges: '1', // THE HACK to make it work
    height: +height + 1, // THE HACK to make it pixel-perfect
  })

  await browser.close()
})()
```

[image]